# Detect if Access Application has error

Tags: ms-access, vba, vbscript

I want to write a script or program to detect If the MS Access application running without errors. If there was an error I would like to know the error number. Is it possible? What is the best way? I would like to write VBScript and run it every 30 minutes. The Access Application that I have is on MS Access 2003.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you write out a log file from the access application. You can use an [error trap](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146864) and the error function to get details of any error that has occured. I do not see how you could do this from VBScript, other than to read such a log.

Comment: tnx.
This application is third party application. I can not change any codes. lately It started to have some errors. I have a timer to run this application and I just wondering if it was possible to check if this application has an runtime error from remote computer or from different program.